# Apache: using vhosts

Tags: apache, xampp, mamp, vhosts

I've added a new entry to vhosts, `d3test`. When I go to `d3test/` in Google Chrome, the page isn't found, `Oops! Google Chrome could not find d3test`.

All of my other entries work fine, for example `graphgram/` shows the correct site.

Here is my vhosts:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /Users/donald/Projects/graphgram
ServerName graphgram
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /Users/donald/Projects/lookgram
ServerName lookgram
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /Users/donald/Projects/d3test
ServerName d3test
</VirtualHost>
```

Why would all entries work except the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added that entry to /etc/hosts aswell? just in case make sure. And restart your service after that.. should work, check what the log says...